# Terraform template using java sdk instead of Terraform CLI

Tags: java, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

I have configured some Terraform templates and I am currently running those using the Terraform CLI.

However I want to run the same from a java application for which I am looking for java SDK alternative of the Terraform CLI. Previously I have seen some cloud vendors like AWS, Azure releasing java sdk which can achieve the functionalities supported by the general purpose AWS Cli or Azure CLI.

Does Terraform have anything similar?

Comment: Why not just shell out?

Comment: terraform underlying is using golang SDK to talk to the service provider, I dont see any need to use Java SDK to do the same thing. Terraform along with tfstate helps resolve the state management issue which it is too troublesome to do with java sdk.

Comment: It can be implemented by running CLI in processbuilder. But toomany things to take care if we go that route.